# jQuery not working, one library working at one time

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery auto complete widget which is using 2 libraries of jquery. I have to use one more code of jquery which is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 $("#id").on('focus',function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
  'scrollTop' : $("#div").position().top
  });
 });
});
```

For this, I have to include another library of jquery.

But using this library, autocomplete widget stops working. I have tried jquery noConflict, but no success.

Comment: which 2 libraries of jquery?

Comment: You only need to include the jquery library once. If you have differing examples which use two different versions of jquery, just include the later version.

Answer (score 0):

You may try putting the jQuery in so called *noConflict* mode, place this before any other jQuery calls:

`var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Also provide more details about the errors and other libraries if this solution does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

use $.noConflict(); inside your script. [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

another way is place jQuery insted of $ inside plugin code for old jquery librarie (This one is Worked for me).